# How to enter x-auth header in postman?

Tags: api, authorization, postman

So I receive an API credential that asks me to enter an X-AUTH-HEADER and Content-Type.

In my postman, on the "Headers" tab, there's a "Content Type" key but I can't see an "X-Auth-Header" key. I only have "Authorization" key. Where to I enter the X-Auth-Header key then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just enter header name and value. You can enter anything you like -- not restricted to suggested options

Answer (score 7):

Custom Headers can just be manually added to the `Headers` section in Postman.

[image: Postman Headers]

Comment: Be attentive. You might need X-Auth-Token, not header

Comment: Not really sure what you mean here, the question asked for `X-Auth-Header`.

Comment: Yeah, actually "X-Auth-Token" search query points to this page, so I tried to help those folks who might have looked for it